# AppFabric error while Set Caching Service configuration

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, appfabric

I am getting the following error while I am trying to set up the AppFabric caching on Windows Server 2008 R2:

> The 'SQL Server AppFabric Cacing Service Configuration Store Provider'
>   does not support Workgroup configurations. Select a different
>   provider.

Is this a known error? Any idea?

Comment: I wish they would explain why somewhere? AppFabric is free so I don't see how it's got anything to do with licensing. UNC shares for a single machine to reference itself just seems icky

Answer (score 1):

If you're installing AppFabric on a standalone machine i.e. not on a domain, you can't use the SQL Server provider for storing the cache configuration data, you'll have to use the XML provider. There's details on what you need to do to the configuration in a Workgroup scenario [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637713.aspx).

Comment: ah, I see. thanks! Actually, for now I will use AppFabric in a single machine so it does not make difference I think, right?

Comment: @tugberk Depends whether your single machine is joined to a domain or not. If it is then you can use the SQL provider, otherwise you'll need to continue with the XML provider.

Comment: No it is not join to a domain. Also, I am not an IT pro and this is my personal machine. So, I need to configure it (I have one more machine, too):s Can you give me a source which leads me how to set up a Domain and join machines into it?

Comment: @tugberk I'm not an IT Pro either, I'm a developer. I can point you at this blog entry I wrote when I was trying to make AppFabric work a couple of years ago - http://philpursglove.blogspot.com/2009/11/installing-appfabric-caching-beta-1_24.html - but I'm not sure how much help it'll be to you.